# Cypress how to make an request on fail

Tags: events, request, cypress

I am trying to trigger an action when the test failed (which will send me an email).

```
Cypress.on('fail', (error, runnable) => {
cy.request('POST', 'https://mysite/api/', { action: 'cypress', error : error, runnable: runnable })
    throw error
})

describe('Test https://xxx/', function() {
    it('Visits the Page', function() {
        cy.visit('https://xxx/yyy/')
        .location('pathname').should('eq', '/yyy/thank-you')
    })
})
```

But when i execute it i get this premise error:

```
CypressError: Cypress detected that you returned a promise from a command while also invoking one or more cy commands in that promise.

The command that returned the promise was:

  > cy.location()

The cy command you invoked inside the promise was:

  > cy.request()
```

Is there a way to call a post request from a fail event?

Thank you

Comment: Interesting. How are your test automatically running? Are you using Jenkins or some other continuous integration tool?

Comment: Didnt get that far, first i want to make sure that the notification works, but cypress has command line functionality, so that should not be a problem: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line.html#Installation

Comment: I ask because your continuous integration runner would be responsible for sending an email. For instance at my job we use Jenkins to run our Cypress test and Cypress has a method of sending emails if a test fails. This works for our jasmine test, c# Nunit test, etc... Good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with a plain `fetch()`. Note that `runnable` has circular references, so you may want to pluck out some parts for the message.

```js
Cypress.on('fail', (error, runnable) => {
  fetch('https://mysite/api/', {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(runnable.title), // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
  });
  throw error
})
```

In my test this doesn't throw the nested promise error, and I can see the POST pending in the network tab so presume it's going to work with a kosha api in place.

Comment: Since this is executed in the browser context it is subject to CORS and the request cannot be made to external domains...

Comment: I tried and in my case I can say that the function works fine